# Exemple de phrase avec "jasées"

Tags: participe-passé

Jaser est un verbe intransitif avec l'auxiliaire avoir. Pourtant, le mot "jasées" est accepté au Scrabble.

Dans quelle phrase peut-on l'utiliser?

Comment: Étonnant effectivement. Sur quelle source vous appuyez vous pour indiquer que le Scrabble accepte ce mot ?

Comment: @Damien: https://1mot.net/jases

Comment: @Toto Merci pour cette information. Effectivement, on y trouve un extrait de l'ODS, qui est la référence officielle. Donc cela confirme que ce mot est bien accepté... J'ai aussi lu que ce verbe est utilisée au Québec avec un sens un peu différent. Peut-être que cette orthographe vient de là, je n'ai pas réussi à trouver beaucoup d'informations sur le sujet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On ne touve ni « jasées » ni « jasée » dans les livres ([ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=jas%C3%A9e%2Cjas%C3%A9es&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=)).

On ne trouve pas ce mot non plus dans cette source : https://fr.glosbe.com/fr/fr/jas%C3%A9es.

Dans la  conjugaison du verbe  telle que reconnue par cette [source (conjugaison Le monde)](https://conjugaison.lemonde.fr/conjugaison/search?verb=jaser) ne figure que  le participe passé masculin, alors que pour le verbe « passer » par exemple sont listées toutes les formes du participe passé. Il en est de même dans la source suivante : [conjugaison Le Figaro](https://leconjugueur.lefigaro.fr/conjugaison/verbe/jaser.html). Ceci est une indication que ces formes (jasés, jasée, jasées) ne sont pas employées ou bien si on les trouve sur le papier ce doit être  dans de très rares cas, dans des œuvres poétiques. Personnellement je ne connais pas cet usage.

Le chant du geai est appelé un jasement et l'on dit de le [geai jase](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geai_des_ch%C3%AAnes#Chant). Il me semble qu'il serait tout à fait logique de construire des phrases contenant ces formes, telles que la suivante par exemple.

- Ses notes, jasées plus distinctement maintenant, me semblaient peu musicales.

Il est évident que si l'on peut dire

- « Ses notes, chantées plus distinctement maintenant, me semblaient peu musicales. »,

on a une bonne raison de parler de « notes jasées », mais je n'ai cependant pas trouvé de trace de cet emploi.

Answer (score 1):

Il se trouve que je suis joueur de Scrabble moi-même, et que je possède donc une copie de l'ODS. C'est une antiquité de 20 ans d'âge (3e éd.), mais puisuqe la définition clé y est, cela n'a pas d'importance.

Il faut comprendre que les définitions de l'ODS sont aussi minimalistes que possible, généralement juste assez pour définir un mot inhabituel, ou justifier un pluriel ou (comme dans le cas qui nous intéresse), une transitivité inattendue.

En l'occurrence, sous *jaser*, on trouve une définition de ce type, et d'un laconisme typique de l'ODS, d'ailleurs: "Québ. Raconter." Le verbe *raconter* étant transitif, c'est clairement sur la base de ce sens que jaser a été marqué transitif (si ce changement a été appliqué dans cette édition ou une précédente, je ne saurais dire).

Personnellement, je suis québécois et ce n'est pas un usage du verbe *jaser* auquel je suis accoutumé, et je ne sais pas d'où le comité de rédaction de L'ODS l'a sorti.

Answer (score 0):

D'après cette [source](https://dicocitations.lemonde.fr/conjugaison-verbe/index.php?word=jaser), on a pour le participe passé :

- jasé
- jasés
- jasée

Pourquoi  *jasées* n'est pas présent ? C'est un mystère.

Comment: Pas un mystère: le site est mal programmé, car il n'indique le participe passé féminin pluriel pour *aucun* verbe.